# Scala, making a Set if in condition met and MutableSet otherwise

Tags: scala

I want to make this lazy bal such that it's a Set when condition not met and mutable.Set otherwise

I thought this would work

Then I do when condition = True,

```
def getSetOrMutableSet(): Either[mutable.Set[Long], Set[Long]] = {
    if (condition) {
      Left(mutable.Set[Long](11,11))
    }
    else {
      Right(Set())
    }
  }

  lazy val GOTTENSET = getSetOrMutableSet().fold(
    right => right,
    left => left
  )
```

When I try

`GOTTENSET+=14`

However, when I run my code, I get

`value += is not a member of scala.collection.Set[Long]`

Seems as if my code is always expecting a Set

Comment: What is really the meta-problem you are trying to solve having either a mutable or an immutable set?

Comment: I'm trying to return a MutableSet if I condition is met and a Set if not. But if I return an Immutable set it infers a set and the code won't compile

Comment: To be clear, I am doing this because if I am in test, I want to add an element to the set, if I am not in test I do not want to have this capability

Comment: You're in a test and you know for sure the type? If so, just use `.left` or `.right` to retrieve the type. You'll get an exception if it fails but it makes sense in a test.

Answer (score 2):

The inferred type of `GOTTENSET` is indeed (immutable) `Set[Long]`, thus the error.

Why? Because `Set` is the most specific common type between `mutable.Set` and `Set`. The return type of `fold` is this most specific common type.

You can't write safely `+=` without knowing if your variable is actually a mutable set or not.

You could still pattern match to check the runtime type but in this case, it's better to keep the `Either`.

*I would recommend to keep working with `Either[mutable.Set, Set]` if you really need to handle both types of set, or just stick to immutable sets in the 1st place. This depends what you're trying to achieve with this code and we can't give more guidelines without more context but such code is definitely a "smell".*

Comment: How would I be able to keep working with either and at the same time have the code compile when using +=?

Comment: Pattern matching for instance?

Comment: I was not able to get it working through pattern matching, I tried the following two

`if (GOTTENSET.isInstanceOf[MutableSet[Long]]) {
  GOTTENSET+=1
`

`GOTTENSET match {
  case mutableSet: MutableSet[Long] => GOTTENSET += 1
  case _ => _ // do nothing
}
`

Comment: I'd recommend you read a bit more about the basics. You need to use `mutableSet += 1` and not `GOTTENSET` in the pattern match. And don't use the instanceof thing.